# Extend indexation of list python

Tags: python, list

I have the following code to extend a list by splitting the string at the `;` delimiter:

```
original_list = ['str_1; str_2; str_3', 'str_1; str_2; str_3', 'str_1; str_2; str_3']
original_labels = [7,8,9]

final_list, final_labels = [], []
for i,element in enumerate(original_list):
    new_list = element.split(';')
    final_list.extend(new_list)
    new_labels = [original_labels[i]]*len(new_list)
    final_labels.extend(new_labels)

print(final_list)
# ['str_1', ' str_2', ' str_3', 'str_1', ' str_2', ' str_3', 'str_1', ' str_2', ' str_3']
print(final_labels)
# [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9]
```

Is there a more efficient/elegant way to implement this, e.g. without the `for` loop?

Comment: I don't think so. You can't easily use a list comprehension because you're creating multiple lists.

Comment: Will you evet zip them at some point?

Answer (score 2):

A more pythonic way of doing it is:

```
original_list = [
    'str_1; str_2; str_3', 
    'str_1; str_2; str_3', 
    'str_1; str_2; str_3',
]
original_labels = [7, 8, 9]

# Create a generator not a list
str_lable_list = (
    (individual_str, original_labels[idx]) for idx, combined_str in enumerate(original_list) for individual_str in combined_str.split(';')
)
final_list, final_labels = zip(*str_lable_list)

assert final_list == (
    'str_1', ' str_2', ' str_3', 
    'str_1', ' str_2', ' str_3', 
    'str_1', ' str_2', ' str_3',
)

assert final_labels == (
    7, 7, 7, 
    8, 8, 8, 
    9, 9, 9,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This avoids the for-loop, and uses a *nested list comprehension* instead, it is more concise but can be harder to understand if you're not used to the syntax, I believe it should be similar in performance because it doesn't calculate anything twice, however iterating multiple times can be costly:

```
original_list = ['str_1; str_2; str_3', 'str_1; str_2; str_3', 'str_1; str_2; str_3']
original_labels = [7,8,9]

lists = [l.split(";") for l in original_list]
final_labels=[l for i, label in enumerate(original_labels) for l in [label] * len(lists[i])]
final_list=[l for sl in lists for l in sl]
```